# java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root

Tags: sonarqube, centos7

CentOS 7

SonarQube 7.9.1

When I try to run sonar like this:

```
sudo ./sonar.sh start
```

I get error:

```
2021.05.18 17:02:32 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) [elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
2021.05.18 17:02:32 WARN  es[][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Consider marking @raspy's answer as answered; guidance is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't. As stated, it should not run as root. Refer to [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/setup/operate-server/#header-2) for instructions on starting the server.